# Rich:poppuppanel don't open

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I can not open a rich: popPupPanel someone could help me my code is as follows

```
<a4j:commandButton  value="Pergunta" action="#{gameController.buscarPergunta()}" render="painelPergunta" ></a4j:commandButton>
    <a4j:outputPanel ajaxRendered="true" id="panelPopPup">
        <rich:popupPanel id="popup" modal="true" autosized="true" resizeable="false">
            <h:outputLabel value="testando..." />
        </rich:popupPanel>
    </a4j:outputPanel>

<a4j:commandButton value="Responder" actionListener="#{gameController.responder()}" oncomplete="#{rich:component('popup')}.show()}" render="painelPergunta panelPopPup">
```

Comment: can you remove the last `}` from `#{rich:component('popup')}.show()}`?

Comment: has missing the show attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a4j:commandButton  value="Pergunta" SHOW="TRUE" action="#{gameController.buscarPergunta()}" render="painelPergunta" ></a4j:commandButton>
<a4j:outputPanel ajaxRendered="true" id="panelPopPup">
    <rich:popupPanel id="popup" modal="true" autosized="true" resizeable="false">
        <h:outputLabel value="testando..." />
    </rich:popupPanel>
</a4j:outputPanel>
```

FALTAVA O ATRRIBUTE SHOW